# Can predictions be trusted if learning curve shows validation error lower than training error?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I'm working with neural networks (NN) as a part of my thesis in geophysics, and is using TensorFlow with Keras for training my network.

My current task is to use a NN to approximate a thermodynamical model i.e a nonlinear regression problem. It takes 13 input parameters and outputs a velocity profile (velocity vs. depth) of 450 parameters. My data consists of 100,000 synthetic examples (i.e. no noise is present), split in training (80k), validation (10k) and testing (10k).

I've tested my network for a number of different architectures: wider (5-800 neurons) and deeper (up to 10 layers), different learning rates and batch sizes, and even for many epochs (5000). Basically all the standard tricks of the trade...

But, I am puzzled by the fact that the learning curve shows validation error lower than training error (for all my tests), and I've never been able to overfit to the training data. See figure below:

[image]

The error on the test set is correspondingly low, thus the network seems to be able to make decent predictions. It seems like a single hidden layer of 50 neurons is sufficient. However, I'm not sure if I can trust these results due to the behavior of the learning curve. I've considered that this might be due to the validation set consisting of examples that are "easy" to predict, but I cannot see how I should change this. A bigger validation set perhaps?

To wrap it up: Is is necessarily a bad sign if the validation error is lower than or very close to the training error? What if the predictions made with said network are decent?

Is it possible that overfitting is simply not possible for my problem and data?

Comment: I cannot see any issue with the displayed error curves...

Comment: It's not a problem. It just means that your validation set is very close of your training set and that the NN do a great job at finding the structure. It is absolutely possible that you don't have noise in your datas and as such it performs well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a non-issue.

Comment: Thank you. It's my first time working with NN's and since overfitting seems to be the most common issue when training I found it strange that it didn't occur for my case.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to trying a higher k fold and the additional testing holdout sample,perhaps mix it up when sampling from the original data set: Select a stratified sample when partitioning out the training and validation/test sets. Then partition the validation and test set without stratifying the sampling.

My opinion is that if you introduce more variation in your modeling methodology (without breaking any "statistical rules"), you can be more confident in the model that you have created.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve more trustworthy results by repeating your experiments on different data. Use cross validation with high fold (like k=10) to get better confidence of your solution performance. Usually neural networks easily overfit, if your solution has similar results on validation and test set its a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy to tell when not knowing the exact way you have setup the experiment:

- what cross-validation method did you use?
- how did you split the data?
- etc

As you mentioned, the fact that you observe validation error lower than training can be a result of the fact that either the training dataset contains many "hard" cases to learn or the validation set contains many "easy" cases to predict.

However, since generally speaking training loss is expected to underestimate the validation, to me the specific model appear to have unpredictable/unknown fit (perform better in predicting the unknown that the known feels indeed weird).

In order to overcome this, I would start experimenting by reconsidering the data splitting strategy, adding more data if possible, or even change your performance metric.

Comment: Thank you, I actually haven't used any cross validation method but I'll try that out!